# Why can you remove constant when taking the derivative?

Tags: differentiation, calculus

If the derivative of a constant is 0, why can we just remove this constant when differentiating?

eg.
If d/dx(3x^2+5x+1), can we write this as d/dx(3x^2)+d/dx(5x)+d/dx(1).

If so, what allows us to do this, isn't d/dx not a number?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 5):

$d/dx$ is an operator, not a number. It maps functions to other functions. But it is a linear operator, which means $$\frac{d}{dx}(a f(x) + b g(x))=a \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) + b \frac{d}{dx}(g(x)).$$
Note that if $a$ or $b$ are zero, that means that term will become the zero function that is always zero.